# grunt-ec2 hangs when trying to execute grunt-ec2 commands (to manipulate amazon ec2 bucket)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I am using https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-ec2 to connect to, and update a bucket for, Amazon AWS. When I execute any of the ec2 commands (for example: grunt ec2_list_json:all) it hangs and never responds. Here are what the relevant files look like:

Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-04-28 using angfull 1.4.2
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    ec2: 'aws-credentials.json',

    ...

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ec2');

  ...
```

aws-credentials.json

```
{
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxx",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "xxx",
  "AWS_SECURITY_GROUP": "xxx",
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-east-1d",
  "AWS_IMAGE_ID": "ami-05355a6c",
  "NODE_SCRIPT": "server.js"
}
```

When I execute a command that requires connecting to the AWS instance - it hangs. Clearly it isn't connecting at all - I'm just not sure why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config should be as follows:

```
{
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxx",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "xxx",
  "AWS_SECURITY_GROUP": "xxx",
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-east-1",
  "AWS_IMAGE_ID": "ami-05355a6c",
  "NODE_SCRIPT": "server.js"
}
```

Basically, `us-east-1d` is an availability zone within `us-east-1` and not a region.

Comment: thanks - ill give it a shot...messing with openshift now too - reading something about "walking" mongodb on amazon ec2...is that a necessary tactic for getting a t1.micro server working with mongo? if so - what is "walking" exactly? I read an article but I don't fully understand it  yet.

Comment: I already set up mongo and it is running on the server (after much configuration) - but I am only using t1.micro for "test production" basically, a little general advice would be awesome!

Comment: for example - what should I set mongodb:///xxx to for amazon ec2 t1.micro server?

Comment: @ewizard  if your mongodb server is in the same EC2 region you can set it to the mongodb's server internal IP address.